# ORA-06550 PLSQL encountered the symbol DROP

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the below code.

```
BEGIN
  NULL;
END;
DROP TABLE TEST_1;
CREATE TABLE TEST_1 AS
select 1 h from dual;
```

However, when executing as a script (F5) in SQL Developer, the below error is thrown. What is the way around this?

```
ORA-06550: línea 4, columna 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DROP" 
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: what is the point of your begin/end block?  You need to put a / after it

Comment: @OldProgrammer thanks, that solved the issue. If you would like to post it as an answer, I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a / after the begin/end block.